# Pandas group by and aggregate for 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table with dates of several years but also several values for the same day, no column is unique in the input table, so the index is [1,2,3,4...]

input:

```
      date  mon day Data_Value
20/7/2020   7   20  4
20/7/2020   7   20  7
20/8/2020   8   20  52
4/7/2020    7   4   6
```

I want to use group by and aggregate for all unique combinations of day-month

Desired output

```
date       mon  day Data_Value
20/7/2020   7   20  4
20/8/2020   8   20  52
4/7/2020    7   4   6
```

If I can get the same result with other method is ok
I tried

```
df_min = df2.groupby('day')['month'].aggregate({'Data_Value':np.min})
```

and

```
df_min = df2.groupby(['day','month']).aggregate({'Data_Value':np.min})
```

But I couldn't make it work

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you need ``drop_duplicates`` rather than groupby.

Comment: `df2.groupby(['mon', 'day'],sort=False,as_index=False).agg(np.min)`?

Comment: @Sushanth Not really, OP needs to keep min value (I'm assuming that's what OP meant not sure tho).